# MySQL's CurDate() function error (non syntactical)

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a background script that uses MySQL's CurDate() function to check if a date in a field in a table of my database has passed, and then to execute `mysql_query("UPDATE table SET"); etc...`  Here is the current code I have, but the problem is the query is update every field, whether or not the date has passed... Please help!  Thanks!

---

PHP/MySQL

```
    <?php 

        require ("connect.php"); 

        mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE active='1'");

        mysql_query("UPDATE files SET active='0' WHERE fortest < CurDate()")        

    ?>
```

Comment: So does `SELECT * FROM files WHERE fortest < CurDate()` select all records?

Comment: What is `fortest` defined as? It's not an issue to do with differently configured date fields, is it?

Comment: @xdazz No, I am first selecting all of the entries from files where the active field='1'  Then, I am running an Update query to set active to 0, if the date has already passed, using WHERE fortest < CurDATE()

Comment: Than it should be `WHERE fortest > CurDATE()` .
Am I right? The date you are comparing should be AFTER CURDATE().

Comment: I don't think so... @andrewsi

Comment: @Zagor23 No, because the date should have already passed, so the current date should be greater than the date in the table

Comment: Could you give us some example data of the fortest column please? Is this date somewhere in the future or in the past?

Comment: Also I think you misunderstand databases a bit, if I got you right there. When you select rows where active=1, you get the rows, but your database server doesn't remember that (no matter which RDBMS you are using). So you might want to write `UPDATE files SET active='0' WHERE fortest < CurDate() AND active = '1'`.

Comment: @RobForrest past/present, i.e. the date of the meeting is on 07-08-2012, following a mm-dd-yyyy format.  Since the meeting was yesterday, it was still active, and it will still have active=1 today as well.  However, tomorrow, since the date has passed, the query will set active to 0.

Comment: @tombom Ahhh... ok, let me see...

Comment: If that's the case then your logic is right but what is the datatype of the fortest column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your fortest field is a MySQL date then your code is more or less correct. If you are storing a string (e.g. "07-08-2012") then you will need to change the way you are doing it.

Can you run this and paste the results...

```
SHOW fields FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Thank you!  You just made me realize that I was storing it as a string, and in a mm-dd-yyyy format INSTEAD of yyyy-mm-dd!  Thanks!  I originally had it as  a string.

Comment: It was the only thing I could think of because your code looked fine. Glad it helped.